# Log-transforming time series data before cointegration testing

Tags: time-series, data-transformation, cointegration, logarithm

I am testing the cointegration between these variables:

Gold Price (Ringgit),
Exchange Rate - MYR to USD (Ringgit),
Real Effective FX Rate Based on CPI,
T-Bill 10 Years Rate,
Consumer Price Index.

Which variables should I take logarithms of before running the tests?

Comment: Gold Price (Ringgit), Exchange Rate - MYR to USD (Ringgit), Real Effective FX Rate Based on CPI, T-Bill 10 Years Rate, & Consumer Price Index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, Exchange rate is logged, CPI is logged, Gold Price is logged. Interest rates are left like this.

I would suggest, however, to apply the following transformations, because people usually use those: CPI becomes inflation and exchange rate becomes a ap-/depreciation rate.

Comment: So why not we log for interest rate? And then i am actually taking all the data in differenced form for all the tests (stationary, johansson & engel granger, var). Is it the correct way?

Comment: Because it makes no sense to log an interest rate. How would you interpret it ? You take the log of a series because you suspect an underlying exponential form. This is not the case for interest rates.

Comment: I have another question. Say for differenced formation. Do i  do the first difference for all variables or it depends on the nature of data. For eg. consumer price index?

Comment: Your aim is to have stationary variables when estimating. Thus, those which are stationary should not be differenced.

Comment: So we should just go for stationarity test first before deciding on the differencing formation?